# android asynctask retrieve after re-enter an activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to build a "smart downloader" that can download images in background (using AsyncTask).
   There are two Activity, A and B. In activity A, I can choose the image list I want to view, (first download if not have been download once). Then enter activity B, here I launch a asynctask to download the image in background and in the UI thread, show the image to the user.

there are some large list that may take minutes to finish downloading. One tricky problem is when the asynctask is still downloading the list, the user may exit activity B (come back to activity A. (I know the asyntask will still continue working even if activity B is destroyed). 
   But if at this time user choose another list to view (then enter activity B). I want to stop the previous task for a while, began to downloading the new list first, and then the old list.
   My thoughts to do that is retrieve the previous asynctask and modify the downloading order. But I don't know how to retrieve the asynctask, I have search some questions about recreate asynctask, but they are all about after re-configuration (like rotate the screen). is there a way to retrieve the background working asynctask, after i destroy the activity and recreate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once you destroy an Activity, the AsyncTask is gone. For this reason, AsyncTasks are not the optimum solution if you want to avoid running the background operation from scratch.

I think you should structure your app to download images using an IntentService. In activity A, choose the image list. Once it's chosen, fire off an IntentService to download the images. Once the IntentService is done, it can notify the user that the operation is complete or send a local broadcast message back to the activity. In either case, even if the user has navigated away from the activity, the work hasn't disappeared. If the activity was destroyed, you can figure out if the download is done, and if so, display the images. If it's not done, you can put up an activity indicator.